# Text file empty after using .write()

Tags: python, file-io

I'm a beginner at python and im just trying to do some simple file I/O questions.

I wrote this code:

```
sentence=input("give a sentence:")
f=open("wordsOnLine.txt",'w')
f.write(sentence)
f.close
```

I just want a sentence that a user inputs to be saved in a text file. I was going to use that file for a different part of the question, but after running the code, inputting a test sentence, and checking the file, it's just empty. I didn't get any errors either.

Idk what im doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f.close` is a method so you need to give it `()` like so: `f.close()`

Comment: Ah thanks. IDK why i didnt catch that after looking over it so many times lol

Comment: @Alfie You're right, but the file would close automatically when the program exits, so that likely isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Either add parenthesis like `f.close()`, or use `with:` (a more common approach).

```py
sentence=input("give a sentence:")

with open("wordsOnLine.txt",'w') as f:
    f.write(sentence)
```

In your case,

```py
sentence=input("give a sentence:")
f=open("wordsOnLine.txt",'w')
f.write(sentence)
f.close()
```

Comment: If you're using `with`, you don't need `close()`.